# How to get the month in the given date

Tags: oracle, date

I just want to get the Month in the given date

Ex. I have a list of date in my entity

```
01/02/2012
01/03/2012
03/01/2012
```

Comment: @VijayVerma he is on Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

```
select to_char(date_value,'MM') from dual;
select to_char(date_value,'Mon') from dual;
select to_char(date_value,'Month') from dual;
```

?

Comment: what do you think off the "extract" syntax? (`select extract(month from date_value) from dual`)

Comment: @wolφi it is ok, mostly because is ANSI SQL standard, but I'm using to_char as a habit.

Comment: Thanks. SELECT to_char(date_value,'MM-YYYY') from dual is fine too :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get month number like `01` then try this

```
select to_char(date_val,'MM') from dual
```

For `Mon` try this

```
select to_char(date_val,'Mon') from dual
```

For `Month` try this

```
select to_char(date_val,'Month') from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

To_Char(): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions200.htm#SQLRF06129
Date Formats for To_Char(): docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34510
Extract(): http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions059.htm#SQLRF00639